# Trivial Tangent and Cotangent Bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

If we have a smooth manifold $M$, why is the tangent bundle $TM$ trivial (as a vector bundle) iff the cotangent bundle $T^*M$ is trivial as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Given a global frame for either, there is a pretty natural way to create a global frame for the other by dualizing or taking the "covector".

Comment: Are you assuming that $TM$ has a metric when you say dualizing?

Comment: @Sanchez No, I literally meant taking the covector. The cotangent bundle is the dual bundle to the tangent bundle, and vice-versa. This allows us to take a global frame $\{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n\}$ and "dualize" to a global frame $\{\sigma_1^\ast,\ldots,\sigma_n^\ast\}$.

Comment: But how can you ensure the new global frame is continuous?